# How to add a timestamp to the filename when unloading from Snowflake to S3?

Tags: sql, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created a task that unloads a CSV file into an S3 bucket. However, the file name only displays the {current_timestamp} string instead of the actual timestamp as I had intended. How can I modify the SQL below to include the current timestamp in the file name?

```
create or replace task MANAGE_DB.PUBLIC.TASK_TEST_S3_3
    warehouse=COMPUTE_WH
    schedule='1 MINUTE'
    as COPY INTO @MANAGE_DB.EXTERNAL_STAGES.snow_s3_stage/{current_timestamp}.csv
FROM (
SELECT *
FROM MANAGE_DB.PUBLIC.LANGUAGES)
OVERWRITE=TRUE
FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = 'CSV', COMPRESSION = 'GZIP');
```

[image]

Comment: You can add it after appending as a string

`as COPY INTO @MANAGE_DB.EXTERNAL_STAGES.snow_s3_stage/LANGUAGES_{current_timestamp()}.csv`

Comment: You were missing round brackets () after current_timestamp.

Does above change work for you ?

Comment: No @Tushar it's not working. I get the error:
syntax error line 4 at position 74 unexpected ')'.
syntax error line 4 at position 75 unexpected '}'. (line 4)

Comment: You would need to create this dynamically and therefore you would have to create it in a stored procedure and get the task to call the SP, rather than it calling a single SQL command

Comment: Can you change the line to :

`as COPY INTO @MANAGE_DB.EXTERNAL_STAGES.snow_s3_stage/'file_' || to_varchar(current_timestamp(), 'YYYY-MM-DD_HH24-MI-SS') || '.csv'`
And try ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use SQL variables or functions in the COPY INTO command for the output filename.
This is added as a note on Snowflake [docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location#required-parameters):

```
The INTO ... value must be a literal constant. The value cannot be a SQL variable.
```

You can include the query id (`INCLUDE_QUERY_ID`) if you want to have a unique part in the filename, but not the current date.